# Hide app-specific settings in the Settings.app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, settings, preferences

I am using a *Settings.bundle* to keep user preferences in my app. By default, they are displayed in the standard *Settings.app*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxWKX.png

I need to be able to hide these so the user cannot access the app preferences from the *Settings.app*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the Settings.bundle, clean all targets, Then Build and Go.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your Settings.bundle and just reference your preference keys using NSUserDefaults.  Settings.bundle just defines how they should appear in the settings app.

Comment: I deleted the _Settings.bundle_, but the user preferences are still displayed in the _Settings.App_! I also deleted the app from the _iphone simulator_ and re-installed it, but to no avail.

Comment: And try to reset your simulator to defaults, then try to re-install the application.